# Bash function that creates an alias gets called endlessly

Tags: command-line, bash-functions

I ran the following Bash function that adds a string with expanded variables, into the end of my `bashrc`:

```
alias() {
    echo "alias $repo=\"$HOME\"/$repo/$repo.sh" >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
    source "$HOME"/.bashrc 2>/dev/null
}
alias
```

To run it I copied it, pasted in the Bash terminal (there it appeared once) and executed by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The output I got in `~/.bashrc` was about a **thousand** lines of the above string:

> alias $repo=\"$HOME\"/$repo/$repo.sh

The very last command (`source /home/user/.bashrc`) kept being executed endlessly (I assume due to endless calling to the function) so I immediately aborted with the `^C` key combo.

---

After removing all thousand repeats of the string with a Nano `mark-set` and cut operation, I desire to ask why did this happen (and keep happening)?

Comment: `alias` is a bash builtin; don't name your functions like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a function called `alias`, added a line to `.bashrc` that calls `alias ...`, and then sourced `.bashrc` into your shell (which has the function defined in it already). The `alias` you sourced calls the function, which adds another line and sources the script again, calling the function again *once for each time it's already run*, leading to exponential growth.

Change the name of your function.

Comment: I changed the name in the routine and call to `setAlias` but still had the problem. Only after I ran `reboot` I no longer had that problem. I don't know why a reboot was needed.

Comment: Because the function was still there in your shell.